# Empty array after appended element

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview, cocoapods

Im trying to upload images to UICollectionView from UIAlertController on the navigation bar. The collection view is located on the other page.

I use BSImagePicker 3rd party library which allows multiple photo selection.

the selectImages() function actually append photos to the selectedImages array and it prints them on the debugger

```
import Photos
import BSImagePicker

class CustomFeedNavigationBar: UIView {

    static let height: CGFloat = 48
    var collectionView = NewPostImagesViewController().collectionView
    var selectedImages: [UIImage] = []

    var rootVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
    unowned var navigationController: UINavigationController

    init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.navigationController = navigationController
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(addPostButton)
    }

    lazy var addPostButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "addPost"), for: .normal)
        button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleAdd), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()

    @objc func handleAdd() {
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Add post", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: { action in
            print("tap dismiss")
        }))
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { action in
            print("tap camera")
        }))
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { action in

            self.selectImages()

            let viewController = NewPostImagesViewController()
            viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
            self.navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        }))

        rootVC?.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

extension CustomFeedNavigationBar {

    func selectImages() {
        let imagePicker = ImagePickerController()
        rootVC?.presentImagePicker(imagePicker, select: { (asset) in
        }, deselect: { (asset) in

        }, cancel: { (assets) in

        }, finish: { (assets) in

            self.selectedImages = []
            let options: PHImageRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

            for asset in assets {
                PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize,
                                                      contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options) { (image, info) in
                    self.selectedImages.append(image!)
                    print("images appended? \(self.selectedImages) YES") // selectedImages array appended elements
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

However when I hit next and go to the next page, the array is empty! and it shows nothing on the debugger

```
class NewPostImagesViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // ...
        // Loaded collection view and etc.

        print("images loaded? \(CustomFeedNavigationBar(navigationController: navigationController!).selectedImages)") // selectedImages array is empty again
    }
}
```

This is the debugger output:

```
images not appended []
images appended? [<UIImage:0x6000030cad00 anonymous {1668, 2500}>] YES
images appended? [<UIImage:0x6000030cad00 anonymous {1668, 2500}>, <UIImage:0x6000030cdf80 anonymous {4288, 2848}>] YES
```

Comment: You're newing up a new instance of CustomFeedNavigationBar in the print

Comment: @Shadowrun I`ve only added the CustomFeedNavigationBar to the print just to access that selectedImages property. Whats the better way to do it?

Comment: No you added "a" (new) CustomFeedNavigationBar, not "the" CustomFeedNavigationBar (that you already had), and that's why the array is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
print("images loaded? \(CustomFeedNavigationBar(navigationController: navigationController!).selectedImages)") // selectedImages array is empty again
```

you create a new instance not the one having the images, so try:

1. ```
   class NewPostImagesViewController: UIViewController {
       var selectedImages = [UIImage]()
   ```
2. ```
   actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { action in

       self.selectImages()

   }))
   ```
3. ```
   let g = DispatchGroup()
   for asset in assets {
       g.enter()
       PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize,
                                             contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options) { (image, info) in
           self.selectedImages.append(image!)
           print("images appended? \(self.selectedImages) YES") // selectedImages array appended elements
           self.collectionView.reloadData() 
           g.leave()
       }
   }

   g.notify(queue:.main) {
      let viewController = NewPostImagesViewController()
      viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
      viewController.selectedImages = selectedImages 
   self.navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
   }
   ```